# Is verse 18:4 meant especially for Christians?

Tags: tafseer, surat-al-kahf

> وَيُنذِرَ الَّذِينَ قَالُوا اتَّخَذَ اللَّهُ وَلَدًا
> and warn those who say, "God has taken a son" - Surah Al-Kahf verse number 4

I am wondering if this verse came for Christians who believe that Jesus was the son of god, of course, it's for everyone that believes that but is it, especially for Christians?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verse is general for everyone who has such a creed. At the time of revelation it included the Christians, the pagans who believed that the angels were daughters of Allah, and the fringe sect of the Jews who held that Uzair was the son of Allah.

**Ref:**

> عن السدي   ... في قوله: وينذر الذين قالوا اتخذ الله ولدا قال: هم اليهود والنصارى
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Abi Hatim](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/2334)</sup>

> عن ابن إسحاق (وَيُنْذِرَ الَّذِينَ قَالُوا اتَّخَذَ اللَّهُ وَلَدًا) يعني قريشا في قولهم: إنما نعبد الملائكة، وهنّ بنات الله
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura18-aya4.html#tabary)</sup>